# why is cmake producing a binary with debug_info and not stripped

Tags: c, cmake

why is cmake producing a binary with debug_info and not stripped?

here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

# project name
project(c-program)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD "90")
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED true)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-ansi -Wall")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g3 -ggdb3")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG")

add_executable(c-program c-program.c)
```

i build like this from the project root folder

`$ cmake -S . -B build/release -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

`$ cmake --build build/release`

when running

`$ file build/release/c-program`

i get

`build/release/c-program: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, with debug_info, not stripped`

i am confused about how debug/release builds are supposed to work, and nothing in the cmake tutorial guides or docs or otherwise online is helping me figure out why this is happening

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` after `project()` does nothing. Use a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) to set `*_COMPILER` variables and `*_FLAGS*` variables.

Comment: @AlexReinking so apparently in a toolchain file we want to set `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT` vars

i have setup a toolchain file


```
# cmake toolchain file

# c flags and flags for debug and release builds
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "-ansi -Wall")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "-g3 -ggdb3")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
```

but still, -DCMAKE_BUILD-TYPE=Release adds debug_info and does not strip

i can't figure this out

Comment: then in the `CMakeOutput.log` file i can see that the `-ansi and -Wall` flags were added during compilation, but the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT` flags were not

Comment: figured it out, it's the linker that is also setting debug_info and not stripping, so adding

`
set (CMAKE_C_LINKER_WRAPPER_FLAG "-Wl,--strip-debug")
set (CMAKE_C_LINKER_WRAPPER_FLAG_SEP ",")
`

to the toolchain file fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some issues with setting flags in `CMakeLists.txt`, so adding and using a toolchain file helped, and setting appropriate `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT` vars in the toolchain file. also, the linker is adding debug info. adding `-s` flag to cmake release flags, and adding `-Wl,--strip-debug` to linker flags is what i was looking for

here is my final `CMakeLists.txt` and `toolchain` files

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

# set toolchain file
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain.cmake"
    CACHE PATH "Path to the desired toolchain file.")

# project name
project(c-program C)

add_executable(c-program c-program.c)
```

```
# toolchain.cmake
# CMake toolchain file

# c compiler and standard
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD "90")
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)

# linker flags
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-Wl,--strip-debug")

# cflags
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "-ansi -Wall")

# cflags for debug build
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "-g3 -ggdb3")

# cflags for release build
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "-O3 -DNDEBUG -s")
```

Comment: No! Do not use the `_LINKER_WRAPPER_FLAG` variables this way. The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINKER_WRAPPER_FLAG.html) is _super_ clear about their purpose. This will break the `target_link_options` command. If you want to add linker flags globally, set `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT` in the toolchain file.

Comment: I've fixed your answer to what you should actually use...